# How to rename existing xticklabels using dictionary in histagram

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, seaborn, xticks

Encounter a problem, how to rename existing xticklabels in lineplot using dictionary ?
Part of code:

```
zodiac_order = ['Aries', 'Taurus', 'Gemini', 'Cancer',  'Leo', 'Virgo', 'Libra', 'Scorpio','Sagittarius', 'Capricorn', 'Aquarius', 'Pisces']    # df_one here is DataFrame
zodiac_counts = df_one["Zodiac"].value_counts()
plt.figure(figsize=(14,6))
zodiac = sns.lineplot(data=zodiac_counts, marker='o', color='mediumvioletred')
zodiac.yaxis.grid(True)
[plt.gca().spines[loc].set_visible(False) for loc in ['top', 'right']]
zodiac.set(xticklabels=zodiac_order) # made list to be in order according to real list of zodiacs
```

I want to change language of *xticks labels*, so have dictionary

```
zodiacs_lt = {'Aries': 'Avinas', 
              'Taurus': 'Jautis', 
              'Gemini': 'Dvyniai', 
              'Cancer': 'Vėžys', 
              'Leo': 'Liūtas', 
              'Virgo': 'Mergelė', 
              'Libra': 'Svarstyklės', 
              'Scorpio': 'Skorpionas', 
              'Sagittarius': 'Šaulys', 
              'Capricorn': 'Ožiaragis', 
              'Aquarius': 'Vandenis', 
              'Pisces': 'Žuvys'
             }
```

[image: lineplot itself]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your data are in a dataframe like this `df`:

```
zodiac_order = ['Aries', 'Taurus', 'Gemini', 'Cancer',  'Leo', 'Virgo', 'Libra', 'Scorpio','Sagittarius', 'Capricorn', 'Aquarius', 'Pisces']
df = pd.DataFrame({'signs': zodiac_order,
                   'values': [6, 1, 6, 5, 6, 8, 1, 6, 4, 1, 5, 1]})
```

output:

```
          signs  values
0         Aries       6
1        Taurus       1
2        Gemini       6
3        Cancer       5
4           Leo       6
5         Virgo       8
6         Libra       1
7       Scorpio       6
8   Sagittarius       4
9     Capricorn       1
10     Aquarius       5
11       Pisces       1
```

you can add a new column to this dataframe with the translated names of zodiac's signs:

```
zodiacs_lt = {'Aries': 'Avinas',
              'Taurus': 'Jautis',
              'Gemini': 'Dvyniai',
              'Cancer': 'Vėžys',
              'Leo': 'Liūtas',
              'Virgo': 'Mergelė',
              'Libra': 'Svarstyklės',
              'Scorpio': 'Skorpionas',
              'Sagittarius': 'Šaulys',
              'Capricorn': 'Ožiaragis',
              'Aquarius': 'Vandenis',
              'Pisces': 'Žuvys'}
df['new_signs'] = list(map(lambda x: zodiacs_lt[x], df['signs']))
```

output:

```
          signs  values    new_signs
0         Aries       6       Avinas
1        Taurus       1       Jautis
2        Gemini       6      Dvyniai
3        Cancer       5        Vėžys
4           Leo       6       Liūtas
5         Virgo       8      Mergelė
6         Libra       1  Svarstyklės
7       Scorpio       6   Skorpionas
8   Sagittarius       4       Šaulys
9     Capricorn       1    Ožiaragis
10     Aquarius       5     Vandenis
11       Pisces       1        Žuvys
```

Then you can proceed to plot by using `new_signs` column:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(14,6))

zodiac = sns.lineplot(data=df, x='new_signs', y='values', marker='o', color='mediumvioletred', sort=False)
zodiac.yaxis.grid(True)
[plt.gca().spines[loc].set_visible(False) for loc in ['top', 'right']]

plt.show()
```

which gives:

[image]

**Note**:
I deleted the line

```
zodiac.set(xticklabels=zodiac_order) # made list to be in order according to real list of zodiacs
```

which may cause bugs, I realized the same functionality with the `sort=False` parameter in the `sns.lineplot`